# Достать переменную из модели Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, view, model

Здравствуйте.

Есть форма.

Контроллер самый простой:

```
 public function actionIndex(){
   $model = Country::findOne(['id'=>1]);
   if( \Yii::$app->getRequest()->isPost ){
       if( $model->load( \Yii::$app->request->post() ) && $model->validate() ){
          if ($model->save()) {
              return $this->render('index',['model' => $model]);
          }
          else{
              return 1212;
          }
       }
   }
   return $this->render('index',['model' => $model]);
}
```

Но в модели имеется функция:

```
public function TestRules (){
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('manager')) {
        $display = '{update}';
        $displayForm = [];
        return [$display,$displayForm];
    }
    return 122;
}
```

Как можно будет на странице вывести по отдельности строку и массив?

Ведь с моделью идет массив из этой функции.

К примеру, я хочу вывести строчкой на странице {update},

а через n расстояние массив данных $displayForm.

Как это можно реализовать?

Если возвращать return только строчку, то можно на вьюхе применять

```
 $model->TestRules()
```

Надеюсь, проблему и вопрос правильно и понятно объяснил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $model->TestRules();
echo $data[0]; //вывод $display
echo $data[1]; //вывод $displayForm
```